# Autonomic vs Autonomous

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning

What is the difference between the two words "Autonomic" and "Autonomous"?

Are they interchangeable in any situation?

Answer (score 2):

**Autonomic** means **involuntary** and I have only ever heard it used in reference to bodily biological processes.

**Autonomous** means **independent** and I have only ever heard it used in reference to whole organisms and to machinery.

I cannot, off the top of my head, think of any situation in which they are interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however in the sentence "Towards autonomic workload provisioning of ... " that is the title of a published paper we see a different usages that made me ask this question, what do you think about that?

Comment: Huh, learn something new every day.  I'm very curious as to why the practice was named "autonomic" instead of "automatic" and if there was a good reason for it, but it does seem to be industry wide, but I'm not readily finding the original source article.

Comment: This may be something for which the answer is very domain specific.  Since I don't know anything about autonomic server provisioning, I don't know whether "autonomous" (or "automatic") are legitimate synonyms for it.

Comment: It might be worth noting that, of all the 44 results returned by Google when I searched for "Towards autonomic workload provisioning" (yes, there are only 44 occurrences in the world that Google found), all of them point to the same paper: *"Towards autonomic workload provisioning for enterprise Grids and clouds"*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. when I popped "autonomic provisioning" into Google, I got 132,000 hits. I don't know that the "Towards" and the "workload" do anything to find us the origin of the use of "autonomic" this way; they find us that one paper.  Edited to add: 4,130 hits when "autonomic provisioning" is in quotes.